# Checking last character of string does not work

Tags: t-sql

I want to check if user provided valid path. When path does not end with `'/'` or `'\'` I want it to be added by this script.

```
 if ((RIGHT(@FilePath, 1) <> '\') or (RIGHT(@FilePath, 1) <> '/'))
        set @FilePath=@FilePath+'\'
```

Why it doesn't work, unless when I remove `or (RIGHT(@FilePath, 1) <> '/')` from this statement? I mean, it adds `'\'` every time like it was ignoring expression, but when it is just:

`if ((RIGHT(@FilePath, 1) <> '\')`

it works okay.

Comment: Please make your question clear. It sounds like you have a problem and then you say it works ok. ??

Comment: The condition `TRUE OR FALSE` is always `TRUE` (boolean logic). Your last character will always either differ from / or from \. You need to use `AND` instead of `OR`.

Comment: @TT. Using AND instead of OR will not work. AND will mean that both conditions must be satisfied. You can easily achieve this with IN. See my solution.

Comment: @KamranFarzami Indeed both conditions need to be true: the last character need to differ from both / and \.

Comment: @TT. Sorry just had a moment there. You are correct. AND will work also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have `'somepath\'` then the condition `(RIGHT(@FilePath, 1) <> '/')` is true.

When you have `'somepath/'`  then the condition `(RIGHT(@FilePath, 1) <> '\')` is true.

so as a result you will never get the right results.

Try this:

```
if (RIGHT(@FilePath, 1) NOT IN ('\','/')) 
        set @FilePath=@FilePath+'\'
```

Comment: @Dodzik The problem is that one of the OR condition is always comes back true so it doesn't work.